# Match every expression in brackets - REGEX

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex pattern in Java8:

```
\\(*.+?\\)*
```

My test cases are:

```
(1-4*(3^2))*10/5+(10-2)
2+4/2
```

Now the matches are - 
First one: `(1-4*(3^2))` and `(10-2)`.
I want to achieve following matches: `(1-4*(3^2))` and `(3^2)` and `(10-2)` and **not** to catch `2+4/2`. I need this to compute atomized parts and replace in original like: `(1-4*9)` Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You want it to catch both `1-4*(3^2))` and `(3^2)`?

Comment: Trying to correctly match nested braces is the text book CS example for showing the difference in expressiveness of regular languages (matchable by regex) and context free languages (not matchable by regex). You should really not be trying to use regex to evaluate this expression, and if this is homework you're unlikely to get a good score by trying. Use a simple recursive descent parser or something.

Comment: Exactly. Is it even possible?

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks. This is how I thought so. That made my opinion clear. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try `(\(.*\))[^)]+(\(.+\))`...

Comment: @l'L'l That doesn't work...

Comment: @SheshankS.: I'm pretty sure it does... https://regex101.com/r/nb4Exm/1/

Comment: @l'L'l um no??? Match 1
Full match 0-23 `(1-4*(3^2))*10/5+(10-2)`
Group 1. n/a `(1-4*`
Group 2. n/a `(3^2)`
Group 3. n/a `(10-2)` He wants all of them as different matches?

Comment: @SheshankS.: If they weren't different match groups then how would you expect to be able do anything with them mathematically — you couldn't. I'm not sure why you've apparently convinced yourself it can't be done.

Comment: @l'L'l expected output doesn't include `(1-4*`. it has `(1-4*(3^2))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173183/discussion-between-sheshank-s-and-lll).

Comment: @SheshankS.: Here you go: https://regex101.com/r/nb4Exm/2 - cheers!

Comment: @l'L'l Still doesn't work?? It's still giving the same output?

Answer (score 1):

Regex cannot be used to do this kind of thing. It would most likely be easier to use some sort of parsing program (like with python) that uses recursion and checks inside of each bracket pair again.